# Sliver Appbar [Collapsing Toolbar] animate title from left to center in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, flutter-sliver

Here is my Build method for collapsing toolbar:-

```
     @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: CustomScrollView(
        controller: controller,
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: appBarHeight,
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              onPressed: () => null,
            ),
            floating: true,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(

          titlePadding: EdgeInsets.only(left:leftV , bottom:bottomV ),
          title: Text(
            "Title ",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 16.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SliverList(delegate:
          SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(title: Text("Flutter / $index"));
      }))
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

As per the doc I got solution to remove padding :-

> /// By default the value of this property is
>     /// `EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 72, bottom: 16)` if the title is
>     /// not centered, `EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start 0, bottom: 16)` otherwise.
>     final EdgeInsetsGeometry titlePadding;

But I got the output as :-

[image]

I want to center the title when the app bar is totally  collapsed.

Issue has been filed in github also [check here.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11951)

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:**

I ended up creating [a better solution](https://gist.github.com/percula/dd512e6665835e90a509cd89af8db726) that utilizes the transformations already happening within the FlexibleSpaceBar. After copying the file from the gist into your project, replace `FlexibleSpaceBar` with `MyFlexibleSpaceBar` and provide a `titlePaddingTween` such as

```dart
titlePaddingTween: EdgeInsetsTween(begin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, bottom: 16), end: EdgeInsets.only(left: 72.0, bottom: 16))
```

instead of titlePadding. The tween will animate from the "begin" `EdgeInsets` when the appbar is fully expanded to the "end" `EdgeInsets` when the appbar is collapsed.

I also added a `foreground` parameter that displays above the title and background, but doesn't transform as they do.

**Original Answer:**

The other answers are good, but they rebuild more widgets than necessary. My solution builds on the other answers but will only rebuild what is within `ValueListenableBuilder`:

```dart
class SamplePage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const _kBasePadding = 16.0;
  static const kExpandedHeight = 250.0;

  final ValueNotifier<double> _titlePaddingNotifier = ValueNotifier(_kBasePadding);

  final _scrollController = ScrollController();

  double get _horizontalTitlePadding {
    const kCollapsedPadding = 60.0;

    if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
      return min(_kBasePadding + kCollapsedPadding,
          _kBasePadding + (kCollapsedPadding * _scrollController.offset)/(kExpandedHeight - kToolbarHeight));
    }

    return _kBasePadding;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      _titlePaddingNotifier.value = _horizontalTitlePadding;
    });

    return Scaffold(

      body: NestedScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                  expandedHeight: kExpandedHeight,
                  floating: false,
                  pinned: true,
                  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                      collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
                      centerTitle: false,
                      titlePadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16, horizontal: 0),
                      title: ValueListenableBuilder(
                        valueListenable: _titlePaddingNotifier,
                        builder: (context, value, child) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: value),
                            child: Text(
                              "Title"),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                      background: Container(color: Colors.green)
                  )
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: Text("Body text")
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I did end up changing the code I posted in my own own app for performance optimizations, it is indeed better to rebuild only where necessary.

Comment: If anyone gets what this guy does right, then this answer is the best compared to other answers

Comment: Thanks, edited answer working. I have used MyFlexibleSpaceBar and works like champ. You save my day.

Comment: That [gist](https://gist.github.com/percula/dd512e6665835e90a509cd89af8db726) works like a charm

Comment: @Peter Keefe how to move the flexible title to the center of Appbar?

Answer (score 3):

**Found the solution on my own!!!**

Add below code to your **Sliver App Bar** .........

```
 flexibleSpace: LayoutBuilder(
                builder:
                    (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                  double percent =
                      ((constraints.maxHeight - kToolbarHeight) *
                          100 /
                          (appBarHeight - kToolbarHeight));
                  double dx = 0;

                  dx = 100 - percent;
                  if (constraints.maxHeight == 100) {
                    dx = 0;
                  }

                  return Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: kToolbarHeight / 4, left: 0.0),
                        child: Transform.translate(
                          child: Text(
                            title,
                            style: MyTextStyle.getAppBarTextStyle(
                                screenUtil, appColors),
                          ),
                          offset: Offset(
                              dx, constraints.maxHeight - kToolbarHeight),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
```

> Percentage is calculated based on the scroll and it animation has been placed accordingly.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work properly, maybe you could've left some comments explaining your code

Comment: @umni4ek You might want use MediaQuery.of(context).size.width and MediaQuery.of(context).size.height to set your sliver height and other calculations. That way all screen sizes will adjust appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get a solution with a `ScrollController`.

[Example Result Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3lOk.gif)

I used this next function:

```
double get _horizontalTitlePadding {
    const kBasePadding = 15.0;
    const kMultiplier = 0.5;

    if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
      if (_scrollController.offset < (kExpandedHeight / 2)) {
        // In case 50%-100% of the expanded height is viewed
        return kBasePadding;
      }

      if (_scrollController.offset > (kExpandedHeight - kToolbarHeight)) {
        // In case 0% of the expanded height is viewed
        return (kExpandedHeight / 2 - kToolbarHeight) * kMultiplier +
            kBasePadding;
      }

      // In case 0%-50% of the expanded height is viewed
      return (_scrollController.offset - (kExpandedHeight / 2)) * kMultiplier +
          kBasePadding;
    }

    return kBasePadding;
}
```

And I used it inside of my `SilverAppBar` `titlePadding`:

```
  child: Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
    controller: _scrollController,
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverAppBar(
        pinned: true,
        expandedHeight: kExpandedHeight,
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          titlePadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 16.0, horizontal: _horizontalTitlePadding),
```

Just make sure to initialize the controller in `initState()`:

```
_scrollController = ScrollController()..addListener(() => setState(() {}));
```

Comment: This is a good point, but the process slows down the scrolling a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I resolved it using **LayoutBuilder** as the child for the **flexibleSpace** widget of the SliverAppBar. The purpose of the **LayoutBuilder** is to enable me to know the current position (height) of the appBar.

I'm using `MediaQuery.of(context).size` to automatically get the size of the screen.

```
var top = 0.0;
var appbarThreshold = 140.0;

class _MySliverAppBarState extends State<MySliverAppBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return SliverAppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      pinned: true,
      leading: TextButton(
        child: CircleAvatar(
          radius: size.width / 4,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.3),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          print("Hello");
        },
      ),
      leadingWidth: size.width / 4,
      collapsedHeight: size.height / 11.5,
      expandedHeight: size.height / 5,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      foregroundColor: Colors.black,

      flexibleSpace: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          top = constraints.biggest.height;

          return FlexibleSpaceBar(
            title: AnimatedOpacity(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              opacity: 1.0,
              child: Text(
                top < appbarThreshold ? "Bloom" : "Welcome, Iremide",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: top < appbarThreshold
                        ? size.height / 30
                        : size.height / 40,
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    fontFamily: 'SourceSansSerif',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
              ),
            ),
            titlePadding: top < appbarThreshold
                ? EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                    size.width / 4.9, 0.0, 0.0, size.height / 18)
                : EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                    size.width / 14, 0.0, 0.0, size.height / 30),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can adjust the Position of the ***Title when appBar is collapsed*** by editing the left padding size here:

```
//
                titlePadding: top < appbarThreshold
                    ? EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                        size.width / 4.9, 0.0, 0.0, size.height / 18)
                    : EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                        size.width / 14, 0.0, 0.0, size.height / 30),
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
          late ScrollController _scrollController;
          static const kExpandedHeight = 300.0;
        
          @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
            _scrollController = ScrollController()..addListener(() => setState(() {}));
          }
        
          double get _horizontalTitlePadding {
            const kBasePadding = 15.0;
            const kMultiplier = 0.5;
        
            if (_scrollController.hasClients) {
              if (_scrollController.offset < (kExpandedHeight / 2)) {
                // In case 50%-100% of the expanded height is viewed
                return kBasePadding;
              }
        
              if (_scrollController.offset > (kExpandedHeight - kToolbarHeight)) {
                // In case 0% of the expanded height is viewed
                return (kExpandedHeight / 2 - kToolbarHeight) * kMultiplier +
                    kBasePadding;
              }
        
              // In case 0%-50% of the expanded height is viewed
              return (_scrollController.offset - (kExpandedHeight / 2)) * kMultiplier +
                  kBasePadding;
            }
        
            return kBasePadding;
          }
    
    
    CustomScrollView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(
                expandedHeight: kExpandedHeight,
                pinned: true,
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  title: Text(product.title),
                  titlePadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 16.0, horizontal: _horizontalTitlePadding),
                  background: Hero(
                    tag: product.id,
                    child: Image.network(
                      product.imageUrl,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
//add your widgets here
])
        ]
) //end of CustomScrollView
```